# Set Product Category without Loading the Whole Product Model

Tags: product, category, attributes, product-attribute

I'm using this to update the attributes of a product:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes()
```

However, I want to set the category IDs as well. But `$product->setCategoryIds()` is a function not an attribute. Now, it will defeat the purpose of fast product saving if I load the product model just to set the category IDs. Any way I could set the category IDs without loading the product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can.
Just call the product model, assign ID of a product you want to edit, set categories or any other attributes, and save it:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setId(12345);
$product->setCategoryIds(array(3,5,7,11));
$product->save();
```